How can I prevent unloading/leaving (refreshing, clicking on a link and closing) a page using a Pale Moon addon?
I'm trying to make a custom beforeunload confirm dialog using Pale Moon add-on. I achieved displaying a custom dialog on beforeunload event, but I can't make the page not close when choosing "Stay on page" button.
I tried this code, but I get two dialogs, I get the native beforeunload dialog when choosing "stay on page".
function createObserver(topic, handler) {
    return {
        topic,
        observe(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
            if(this.topic != '*' && aTopic != this.topic) return;
            return handler(aSubject, aTopic, aData);
        },
        register() {
            Services.obs.addObserver(this, this.topic, false);
        },
        unregister() {
            Services.obs.removeObserver(this, this.topic);
        },
    };
}

const contentCreatedObserver = createObserver('content-document-global-created', function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    const sandbox = new Cu.Sandbox(aSubject, {
        sameZoneAs: aSubject,
        sandboxPrototype: aSubject,
        wantXrays: false,
    });
    
    aSubject.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
        var evt = aSubject.wrappedJSObject.document.createEvent('Event');
        evt.initEvent('beforeunload2', true, true);
        aSubject.wrappedJSObject.document.dispatchEvent(evt);
        if(evt.returnValue !== undefined || evt.defaultPrevented) && !Services.prompt.confirm(aSubject, beforeUnloadTitle, beforeUnloadHead + '\n\n' + (evt.returnValue ? (evt.returnValue + '\n\n') : '') + beforeUnloadFoot)
            e.preventDefault();
    }, true);
    
    aSubject.wrappedJSObject.window._addEventListener = aSubject.wrappedJSObject.window.addEventListener;
    Cu.evalInSandbox('window.addEventListener = function addEventListener(a, b, c, d) { if(a == "beforeunload") a = "beforeunload2"; return window._addEventListener(a, b, c, d); };', sandbox);
    Cu.evalInSandbox('window.addEventListener.toSource = function toSource() { return "function addEventListener() {\\n    [native code]\\n}"; };', sandbox);
    Cu.evalInSandbox('window.addEventListener.toString = function toString() { return "function addEventListener() {\\n    [native code]\\n}"; };', sandbox);
});

So I tried to make a different code to prevent closing when dom-window-destroyed is fired, but I can't figure out how to cancel this event.
const contentCreatedObserver = createObserver('content-document-global-created', function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    const sandbox = new Cu.Sandbox(aSubject, {
        sameZoneAs: aSubject,
        sandboxPrototype: aSubject,
        wantXrays: false,
    });
    
    aSubject.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
        var evt = aSubject.wrappedJSObject.document.createEvent('Event');
        evt.initEvent('beforeunload2', true, true);
        aSubject.wrappedJSObject.document.dispatchEvent(evt);
        aSubject.preventClosing = (evt.returnValue !== undefined || evt.defaultPrevented) && !Services.prompt.confirm(aSubject, beforeUnloadTitle, beforeUnloadHead + '\n\n' + (evt.returnValue ? (evt.returnValue + '\n\n') : '') + beforeUnloadFoot);
    }, true);
    
    aSubject.wrappedJSObject.window._addEventListener = aSubject.wrappedJSObject.window.addEventListener;
    Cu.evalInSandbox('window.addEventListener = function addEventListener(a, b, c, d) { if(a == "beforeunload") a = "beforeunload2"; return window._addEventListener(a, b, c, d); };', sandbox);
    Cu.evalInSandbox('window.addEventListener.toSource = function toSource() { return "function addEventListener() {\\n    [native code]\\n}"; };', sandbox);
    Cu.evalInSandbox('window.addEventListener.toString = function toString() { return "function addEventListener() {\\n    [native code]\\n}"; };', sandbox);
});

const windowDestroyedObserver = createObserver('dom-window-destroyed', function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    if(!(aSubject instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow)) return;
    if(aSubject.preventClosing) {
        // prevent leaving the page
    }
});

